# I want to use the count of a list within a list for further calculation

Tags: python, function, probability

I have a list within a list. I want to count the frequency of each sublist and use that calculation further.

I am able to count the frequency of each item. But I am not able to move forward.

```
A = [[3,5],[5,6],[6,9],[3,5],[6,9]]
frequency_list=Counter(map(tuple, A))
for key,val in frequency_list.items():
    print(key,val)
```

I want to use this 'val' to calculate a conditional probability.
Example: I want to calculate P(3|5) =P(3and5) (for which I have to access Val) /P(5)

A simple example or hint will suffice.
I am sorry if its too basic, but I am a newbie, thus struggling

Comment: What, exactly, is it you are not able to accomplish? you got the counts, no?

Comment: Yes. Now I want to use this count to calculate something else. How do I access the count of each list

Comment: `frequency_list` is a `dict`. You use it like a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

# Input list initialization
lst = [[3,5],[5,6],[6,9],[3,5],[6,9]]

# Using counter
res = Counter([tuple(el) for el in lst])

# Printing res
print(res)
```

You can find the original code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-count-unique-sublists-within-list/).
The idea is to convert subarray into tuple, and use Counter to count the tuple.
At the end you obtain the number of each subarray.